# C# WPF MVVM и SerialPort

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, serial

Нужно прочитать данные из serial port. Каким образом используя MVVM можно уведомлять View о процессе работы с serial port? Нет гарантий, что данные хорошо придут.. и в модели например метод GetData как оформить если данные читаются в отдельном методе тика таймера?

Comment: Я предвижу вопросы остальных участников, поэтому - можно больше информации и примеров?

Comment: не могу понять как работать с потоком данных используя MVVM

Comment: в данный момент работаю над проектом, где есть чтение через serialPort, в модели у меня реализован метод получения данных.
А само чтение по таймеру реализовано в VM.
Например, у меня есть таймер, который проверяет каждые 10 секунды время в системе. Каждые 10 сек я вызываю этот метод и потом обновляю данные в VM. В чем конкретно вопрос? Что вы подразумеваете под потоком данных?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda можно пример?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda таймер не должен быть в модели?

Comment: Вот первая ссылка в гугле на [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php) про MVVM, почитайте про VM.
MVVM это паттерн, где описаны основные принципы и концепции. Но никто не мешает вам его немного "адаптировать" под свои нужды. В моем случае проще реализовать так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

В конструкторе создаю таймер и привязываю к нему нужный метод:

```
_timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 5000;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += ReadClock;
        _timer.Start();
```

Вот реализация метода:

```
private void ReadClock(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(SelectedPort != null)
        {
            var dateTime = SystemClock.Get();
            if (dateTime != null)
            {
                Time = dateTime.ToLongTimeString();
                Date = dateTime.ToShortDateString();                    
            }                
        }

    }
```

У меня отлавливание ошибок реализовано на более низком уровне, и мне не нужно беспокоиться о правильности данных.

В методе `SystemClock.Get` у меня реализовано чтение из `SerialPort`.

Comment: _timer в ViewModel?

Comment: @MikeWaters в моем случае - да.
У меня есть библиотека, где реализован функционал для работы с внешней системой. А как пользоваться этим функционалом я устанавливаю во VM.

Comment: получается Model хранит только методы для работы а данные получаются в ViewModel?

Comment: В данном случае да. У меня так из системы получается DateTime и потом обновляется нужный контрол.

Comment: @MikeWaters если это не помогает найти решение, то обновите вопрос добавив код с описанием, и я вам попытаюсь помочь.

Comment: а SerialPort в модели?

Comment: @MikeWaters Да.